# Split csv column to multiple columns, group result in pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have an excel table in the below format (Pipe separator to show the different columns.)

```
Project   |Team        |Phase

Project A |W, X, Y     |Initiation

Project B |X, Y, Z, M  |Planning

Project C |Z, M, W     |Execution

Project D |W, X, Z     |Planning
```

I want below results using formulas or pivot:

**Result 1:**

```
Team |Projects

W    |3

X    |3

Y    |2

Z    |3

M    |1
```

**Result 2**

```
Team |Initiation|Planning|Execution

W    |1|1|1

X    |1|2|0

Y    |1|1|0

Z    |0|2|1

M    |0|1|1
```

The max I have done till now is to use text-to-columns to split the csv column in multiple columns. But making pivot on the resultant columns shows all the columns as separate and I am unsure how to group them to get above results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula for result 1: =COUNTIFS($B$4:$B$7,"*w*"), where the B4:B7 range is the column that contains the team and the *w* looks for a w in the whole cell.

Comment: it is returning 0 everytime

Comment: got it, i had to use it like this =COUNTIFS($B$4:$B$7,"*w*")

Comment: sorry for late comment, w is supposed to have asteriks before and after; they didn't show up in the formula.